# How do i create a dynamic array of function pointers?

Tags: c, function, dynamic

i wasn't able to do a dynamic array of function pointers, i have troubles understanding how to work with a dynamic array of function pointers when having a pointer to the func_cmp pointer.

```
int(*func_cmp[])(void *,void*);

numElements++; 
func_cmp=(func_cmp*)realloc(func_cmp, numElements*sizeof(func_cmp*));
func_cmp[numElements-1]=*func_cmp;
```

i'm not sure about the realloc line.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what is wrong in the realloc line? what do i need to make it work?

Comment: I don't think you can create an array of functions; you can create an array of _function pointers_.

Comment: exactly, sorry for the mistaken question, i meant an array of function pointers

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with your `realloc` approach is that calls to `malloc/calloc/realloc` are relatively expensive. So creating an initial bock of pointers sufficient to meet your anticipated needs is generally the best approach. Then call realloc, if and only if you need more. It's a tradeoff. If you are on some embedded system with virtually no spare mem, then your realloc-for-each approach may make sense. Otherwise, allocate a sensible number to begin with an then realloc as-needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearest way is to use `typedef`

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int (*functype)(void *a, void *);

functype funcs[100];  // static array                                           

functype *moreFuncs; // dynamic array

int main() {
  int capacity = 16;  // initial capacity
  int n = 0;          // initial size
  moreFuncs = malloc(capacity*sizeof(functype));  // heap dynamic array

  // ...

  // adding element and need more space
  if (n >= capacity) {
     capacity *= 2;
     moreFuncs = realloc(moreFuncs, capacity);
     moreFuncs[n++] = <address of new function>;
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not usefull if i allocate memmory i won't use, thats why i'm trying to use realloc!

Comment: @user2943683 that's fine -- use `malloc` to allocate the initial array and resize via `realloc` as needed.

Comment: @user2943683 What are you trying to do, exactly? If you have a dynamically allocated block of memory whose size you wish to change, call it like the `malloc` above + the pointer to that memory as the first argument.

Comment: everytime my function receives a function pointer as a parameter i'm trying to use the realloc to add one more funcion pointer to my array, so i have an static int variable which counts every time the function is called and i reallocate the memmory. that's the "numElements++" for in the code above

Comment: @user2943683 the usual scheme is allocate a small amount initially (e.g. `capacity = 10`, `size = 0`) and when `size >= capacity` first double the `capacity` , `realloc` using the new `capacity`, add the new element, and increment the `size`.  Calling `realloc` each time you add an entry is generally not a sensible way to resource memory.

Comment: It may also be worth pointing out that keeping a `char *` array of the function names added to `moreFuncs` allows coordinating the pointer array contents with the actual function names rather than just by index. Additionally, keeping a sentinel `NULL` as the last element in each allows iteration without the need to pass a size, which is also very useful when passing function pointer arrays as arguments. As to initial size of block to create, it is generally **based on a reasonable estimate of the amount actually required**. There is no fast an hard rule, but if you anticipate 50, create 50.